# .NET Core WebApi Authentication & Authorization via Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for the best way to authenticate my .NET Core API with Azure.
The API should only be accessible for people or other applications that have a valid key.

I need to be able to the following:

- Add a **new token inside Azure** for a customer/application to access the API
- Set the **activation and expiration dates** for a token (or enabled & disabled)
- In .NET Core use the [**Authorize**] attribute to authorize the user to access the endpoint

What would be the best solution to do this with Azure ?

I was thinking about **Azure Key Vaults**, but I do not know how I can use the [Authorize] attribute with Azure Key Vault ?

OR

Are there any other solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about Azure Key Vaults, but I do not know how I can use the [Authorize] attribute with Azure Key Vault ?

You cannot use Azure key vault to authenticate your core webapi. Because [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts) is **a tool for securely storing and accessing secrets**. A secret is anything that you want to tightly control access to, such as API keys, passwords, or certificates.

> Are there any other solutions?

In ASP.NET Core you could Microsoft identity platform and Azure Active Directory to authenticate and authorize your webapi.

You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/calling-a-web-api-in-an-aspnet-core-web-application-using-azure-ad/) which the ASP.NET Web application uses the OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.NET) to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The bearer token is passed to the web API, which validates the token and authorizes the user using the JWT bearer authentication middleware.

Comment: Ok, so how does it work ? I define a user/application that should have access to the API and then Azure generates me a Jwt Token that I can give to the user/application, which he has to provide in each request?

Comment: You use the client app to get jwt token. And use the token to authenticate the core api.

Comment: But the Client App should have a shared Token (a token that I will provide him). It is a REST API

Comment: You use client app like a console app to get a jwt token.